# FTP URL form @ character issue

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ftp, nsurl

I need to delete a file from FTP server. But with @ character in UserName making the issue to be failing the deletion with -11 error code.

(If my user name is like SampleUser then it's working fine)

Here is my sample code block:

```
SInt32 errorcode;

NSURL *fullURLWithEscape= [NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://User@app.com:pass123@server.com/testfolder/imagetodelete.png"];
if (CFURLDestroyResource(( __bridge CFURLRef) self.fullURLWithEscape, &errorcode)) {
    // successful
}

else {
    // unsuccessful      
    // GETTING error code = -11  
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error code -11 means [`kCFURLUnknownSchemeError`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Reference/CFURLAccessUtils/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CFURLError):

> Indicates that the scheme is not recognized.

So the URL you've provided is not in a valid form. In a comment to a deleted answer of mine, you said you *are* encoding the password. If so, the URL should be `ftp://User%40app.com:pass123@server.com/testfolder/imagetodelete.png` (instead of `User@app.com` as in your question).

Make sure the URL is indeed encoded correctly (set a debug breakpoint, print the URL; if it's wrong, you need to find out why).

Comment: (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,?%#[]% " did the trick in encoding.!!

Comment: Cool. I suggest you also add `/` to the list.